# Does save_best_only in Keras prevents overfitting?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, cnn, training

I'm training a CNN and using:

```
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(output_artifacts,'weights.h5'), monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True)
```

I trained the network for 70 epochs, but the validation accuracy flattened on good value (90%) after 20 epochs remaining pretty constant.

[image]

[image]

I would say that after epoch 20 (more or less 20:00 in the graph) the network is overfitting. My question is, does save_best_only takes this into account or just save the weights at epochs 1:00 am which is the overall best (but overfitted)?
Should I use earlystopping to stop the training or is not necessary? I don't want to stop the training too early..

Answer (score 2):

It really only tracks the value of the metric you selected, there is no tolerance option. In [**the relevant documentation**](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint), the definition is given:

> save_best_only: if save_best_only=True, the latest best model
>   according to the quantity monitored will not be overwritten.

In your case, combing the callback with the [**EarlyStopping callback**](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) would be the best option. This callback *does* offer some kind of tolerance, i.e. it requires the improvement of the metric to be at least as good as `min_delta` to be considered an improvement.

---

You could combine both callbacks with something like this:

```
from keras.callbacks.callbacks import EarlyStopping

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.05, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint('model_weights.h5', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True)

my_callbacks = [early_stop, checkpoints]
...
model.fit(..., callbacks=my_callbacks)
```

Comment: Is my network overfitting in your opion even if the validation loss stays prettty much constant in the long run ?

Comment: Based on your plots, not really... Perhaps you have some form of regularisation that prevents overfitting (dropout is an example). You could plot `train_acc` with `val_acc` to see if they diverge at all after some time - then the model is overfitting.